# Multiple COUNT() for multiple conditions in one query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have these queries :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'YELLOW';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'BLUE';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'RED';
```

Is there any way to get these results in one query?

Comment: Additional answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23118/152804.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
SELECT color, COUNT(*) FROM t_table GROUP BY color
```

Comment: if the table has more colors, query above returns all colors, not just the 3 selected

Comment: @AdrianBR: That's taking the question rather literally, and failing to see through to the actual underlying problem.

Comment: @eggyal `SELECT color, COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color IN ('YELLOW', 'BLUE', 'RED') GROUP BY color`

Answer (score 75):

If you want the result to be in one row you can use:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(color = 'YELLOW', 1, 0)) AS YELLOW,
    SUM(IF(color = 'BLUE', 1, 0)) AS BLUE,
    SUM(IF(color = 'RED', 1, 0)) AS RED
FROM t_table
```

[Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ef77/3)

Comment: Or just `SUM(color='YELLOW')` etc.

Comment: @eggyal Yes, but it is hard to see what is going on here and you cannot choose to count with weights like `SUM(IF(color = 'YELLOW', 0.75, 0))`.

Comment: Thanks for this one. And the weight thing can be useful also.

Comment: Actually, if you want to return an array with counts for each color, this solution is a better fit.

Comment: Great answer. This is better than the accepted one because sometimes you do not have something that can be grouped. (like when query with different time ranges.)

Comment: Nice bro, very simple but easy to custom 'GROUP BY'

Comment: Good for rows less than few millions, but not a good choice

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT 'yellow' as color ,COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'YELLOW'
union
SELECT 'blue' , COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'BLUE'
union
SELECT 'red',COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'RED';
```

or

```
select color, count(*) from table where color in ('red', 'blue', 'yellow') group by 1
```

Comment: you accepted the only incorrect answer as to your request. your accepted answer returns all colors, not just the 3 you selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using subquery.

```
SELECT(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'YELLOW',
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'BLUE',
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_table WHERE color = 'RED'
);
```

Comment: It appears you need parenthesis around the nested SELECT statements, at least in PostgreSQL.

Comment: are you sure this is one query?!!

Comment: yeah @AliSherafat

Comment: @Faisal If I need to write similar query to update the 1 table from another table with when then, how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can also works for you

```
select count(*) as anc,(select count(*) from Patient where sex='F')as 
        patientF,(select count(*) from Patient where sex='M') as patientM from anc
```

you can also even select and count related tables like this

```
select count(*) as anc,(select count(*) from Patient where 
    Patient.Id=anc.PatientId)as patientF,(select count(*) from Patient where
    sex='M') as patientM from anc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
SELECT sm_med_t_servicios.id as identidad, count(sm_adm_t_admision.id) as cantidad , 
SUM(IF(sm_adm_t_admision.atendido = 'S', 1, 0)) AS atendidos,
SUM(IF(sm_adm_t_admision.atendido = 'N', 1, 0)) AS por_ver

FROM sm_med_t_servicios 
LEFT JOIN sm_adm_t_admision ON sm_med_t_servicios.id = sm_adm_t_admision.sm_med_t_servicios_id
WHERE sm_med_t_servicios.m_empresas_id = '2'
GROUP BY sm_med_t_servicios.id
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but taking Sinte's Answer

[case]
queries requirements
-mutiple item names with mutiple counts

```
select 
t1.person_name

,(
    select count(person_id) from persons where sex='F' and person_id=t1.person_id
)as quantity_M


,(
    select count(person_id) from persons where sex_id='M' and person_id=t1.person_id
) as quantity_F


from persons as t1
group by t1.person_name
order by t1.person_name;
```